# JList strike through

Tags: java, swing

I have a list of data in a JList component in my GUI.

I would like to know if there is a method that i can call on the list element(s) to strike through a particular element in the list. I would like to draw a line through the element to appear as if that element is canceled.

I want a similar thing like the strike through functionality in Microsoft Word document whereby a line i drawn through the text.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can apply html formating to each element of a list.  Therefore if you know what element you want struck through you can modify the string held by that element as such:

```
<html><strike>this text will be struck through</strike></html>
```

Edit: I should note that I haven't tested this so if the strike tag isn't supported in Java try just s.  One of those should work

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tested the strike tag in html and it works. I will test it in my program and see if it will work.

Answer (score 1):

[JIDE Common Layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm) has a [StyledListCellRenderer](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/list/StyledListCellRenderer.html) that can be used to provide this functionality.